# Computation in fixed point or int

Tags: python-3.x, keras, theano-cuda, keras-layer

I am using fixed point numbers within my network based on keras framework. My concern is when there are multiplication operations in the network on theano variables, the result is float32 ( even if the numbers supplied are in fixed point). Is there any intrinsic way to get the result in fixed point format, or even int.

If not, what can be alternative approaches?

Comment: How exactly are you using fixed point in Python?